# Revisions of a theorem where numbering goes 2.0, 2.1,2.2

Tags: math-mode, formatting, counters, ntheorem

I would like to give different equivalent versions of the same theorem, eventually proving the last version. The first time I state the theorem, I would like it to have the number 2.0. Each successive time I revise it, I would like the number to go from 2.n => 2.(n+1). I tried to do this with

```
\newcounter{goalbroad}
\newcounter{goal}
\numberwithin{goal}{goalbroad}
\newtheorem{goal}[goal]{Theorem}
```

and then right before the first

```
\begin{goal}...\end{goal}
```

I call

```
\setcounter{goalbroad}{\value{thms}}
```

But LaTeX (and LuaLaTex) get stuck there.

So far, I have only found explanations on restating a theorem with the same numbering. What is going wrong in my approach, and what would be a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution with `amsthm`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newtheorem*{innergoal}{Theorem \thegoal}

\newcounter{goal}
\setcounter{goal}{-1}
\newif\ifnotfirstgoal

\newenvironment{goal}
 {\ifnotfirstgoal\else
    \global\notfirstgoaltrue
    \stepcounter{thm}%
  \fi
  \xdef\thegoal{\thethm.\noexpand\arabic{goal}}%
  \refstepcounter{goal}%
  \innergoal}
 {\endinnergoal}

\begin{document}

First a theorem.

\begin{thm}
$1+1=2$
\end{thm}

State the goal

\begin{goal}\label{g.0}
$1+0=1$
\end{goal}

Restate the goal

\begin{goal}\label{g.1}
$0+1=1$
\end{goal}

Restate the goal

\begin{goal}\label{g.2}
Easy
\end{goal}

Show the references: \ref{g.0}, \ref{g.1}, \ref{g.2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It appears the names of counters and theorems live in the same namespace, so goal the counter and goal the theorem environment clobbered each other. Changing the counter's name to goalnarrow fixed the problem. I'd still be interested in hearing more info on why and preferred solutions.

Minimum working example:

The relevant bits of my preamble are:

```
\usepackage[amsthm]{ntheorem}
\newcounter{thms} %theorem counter
\newtheorem{theorem}[thms]{Theorem}

\newcounter{goalbroad}
\newcounter{goalnarrow} %this can't be named goal
\numberwithin{goalnarrow}{goalbroad}
\newtheorem{goal}[goalnarrow]{Theorem}
```

Then after the `\begin{document}`, for the first statement of the goal,

```
\stepcounter{thms}
\addtocounter{goalbroad}{\value{thms}}
\begin{goal} %Theorem 2.1
$e^{it}=\cos t + i\sin t$
\end{goal}
```

and then a bit later

```
\begin{goal} %Theorem 2.2
$t\mapsto e^{it}$ is a covering map from \mathbb{R} to the unit circle in the complex plane.
\end{goal}
```

Comment: You should really consider showing an example of this use-case so that the value extends beyond solving just your problem. See how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so we can replicate the setup.